# Call the same jQuery function both on load and on click

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox, load, click

In my "update" pages I have often the need to call the same jQuery function both on page load and on click of some checkbox, mostly like this:

```
function foo(){
    if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')){
        $('.myclass').hide();
    } else {
        $('.myclass').show();
    }
}

$(function() {

    foo(); // this is launched on load
    $('#mycheckbox').click(function(){
        foo(); // this is launched on checkbox click
    })  

});
```

On page load, the checkbox could be checked or not depending on database values: that's why I have the need to launch the foo(); on load

Well, this works fine, but I always wondered if... there is a better or most elegant solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it (assuming that your site contains a server side code component) would be to hide/show the item in the server side render, as appropriate.  This means that there is no screen 'flicker' (however slight it is) on load of the page.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) function to trigger the event immediately;

```
$('#mycheckbox').click(function (){
    if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')){
        $('.myclass').hide();
    } else {
        $('.myclass').show();
    }
}).trigger('click');
```

However, bear in mind that this will also trigger any other click handlers you have defined on the element.

Alternately, you could write a tiny jQuery plugin to do it for you;

```
jQuery.fn.nowAndOn = function (event, handler) {
    handler();

    this.bind(event, handler);

    return this; // support chaining
};
```

And you'd use it like;

```
$(function() {
    $('#mycheckbox').nowAndOn('click', function (){
        if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')){
            $('.myclass').hide();
        } else {
            $('.myclass').show();
        }
    });
});
```

However, the problem with this is that inside the click handler, `this` is normally the current element; whereas by calling `handler();` like we do here, `this` would point to `window` instead (this isn't relevant in the exact snippet you posted, as you don't use `this`).

To fix `this`, we could add some complexity and use the [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) method to set the value of `this`;

```
jQuery.fn.nowAndOn = function (event, handler) {
    this.each(function () {
        handler.call(this);
    });

    this.bind(event, handler);

    return this;
};
```

However, you'll still have a problem if you rely on an Event object being passed...

Answer (score 6):

The best you can do is this:

```
$(function() {

    foo(); // this is launched on load
    $('#mycheckbox').click(function(){
        foo(); // this is launched on checkbox click
    })  

});
```

->

```
$(function() {
    foo(); // this is launched on load
    $('#mycheckbox').click(foo);  

});
```

Answer (score 2):

you could avoid the second function call and bind the function foo directly to the click handler:

```
function foo(){
    if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')){
        $('.myclass').hide();
    } else {
        $('.myclass').show();
    }
}

$(function() {
    foo(); // this is launched on load
    $('#mycheckbox').click(foo)  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered before but this is a another nice way of accomplishing OP's problem, especially with checkboxes in mind, as triggering a click event on an element causes the checkbox to be inadvertently checked/unchecked:

```
$('#myCheckbox').bind('click init', function() {
    $('.myDiv').toggle($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked'));
}).trigger('init');
```

This method also avoids click events propagating.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do would be to call foo() like this:

```
$('#mycheckbox').click(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#mycheckbox').click(function (){
     $(this).is(':checked')?$('.myclass').hide():$('.myclass').show();
}).click();
```